# Laravel 4 view names in controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have a controller named CommentsController and 2 views, the first named searchProducts and the second named searchCategories

in the controller i used:

```
public function getSearchproducts() {
    ...
}
public function getSearchcategories() {
    ...
}
```

.... so the url generated is /comments/searchproducts and /comments/searchcategories...

i want to use urls like '/comments/serach-products'  or '/comments/serach_products' is it possible using controllers ??

Comment: It depends on how did you declare the route.

Comment: my route is declared like this
Route::controller('comments', 'CommentsController');

Comment: Yes, you can, answered it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If your controller action contains multiple words, you may access the
>   action using "dash" syntax in the URI.

This is mentioned in [RESTful Controllers](http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#restful-controllers) section. So, `comments/searchproducts` could be used as

```
comments/search-products
```

And method would be

```
public function getSearchProducts() {}
```

Same for `getSearchcategories`, url could be `comments/search-categories` and method

```
public function getSearchCategories() {}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to change the way your routes are built, you'll have to do them manually:

```
Route::get('search-products', 
           array(
                 'as' => 'search.products', 
                 'uses' => 'CommentsController@getSearchproducts'
           )
);
```

And then, when you do

```
URL::route('search-products')
```

It will generate a URI

```
yoursite/search-products
```

I'm not really fan of resourceful controllers, I always create them manually, and nor is Phil Sturgeon as you can see in [this post](http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2013/07/beware-the-route-to-evil).